# db = firebase.database(); is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I have a problem. I want to get all the information from my user, who logged in. The information are included in the Firebase database. When I'm login with the user data, the console give me following error message:

```
subscribe.js:159 TypeError: db.collection is not a function
    at Object.next (index.js:9)
```

How can i fix the error?

**index.js**

```
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.



    var db = firebase.database();
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(user.uid);

    docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
    }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });

    if(user != null){

      var email_id = user.email;


    }

  } else {


  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
       <script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    ...
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: You've definitely called `firebase.initializeApp` first? What does the db object look like - can you try console.log()ging it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please see my Edit! With `console.log(db)` I get: `e {Ie: e, B: t, INTERNAL: e}
B: t {repo: e, path: e, Ae: e, De: false}
INTERNAL: e {database: e}
Ie: e {H: e, app: e, dataUpdateCount: 0, G: null, K: e, …}
app: (...)
__proto__: Object`

Comment: Which database are you trying to use?  Realtime Database or Firestore?

Comment: @DougStevenson I use Firestore

Comment: You need to use `firebase.firestore()` to get the correct object to work with, not `firebase.database()`.

Answer (score 0):

`db.collection()` is not a function because `db` refers to Realtime Database instead of Firestore. They are different databases with different APIs.  We can't tell from your question which database you're trying to use.

If you're trying to use Realtime Database, you will want to use `firebase.database()`, then use `child()` to build a path to a node:

```
var db = firebase.database();
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var docRef = db.child("users").child(user.uid);
```

But if you're using Firestore, you will need to start with `firebase.firestore()`:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(user.uid);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Unfortunately when I'm using `firebase.firestore()` instead of `firebase.database()` I get: `firebase.firestore is not a function`

Comment: You didn't import the firestore script.  Please review the instructions in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment

Comment: Thanks agian! :) I added it with `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>` but same error

Comment: Error: `"firebase.firestore is not a function"`

Comment: Since you have a new problem, I suggest posting a new question that describes what you have so far and what isn't working.  Stack Overflow can only really effectively deal with one thing at a time.

Comment: I know, but it is the same problem.

Comment: No, it's a different problem.  You first problem here was related to the use Firestore APIs on a Realtime Database object.  Your new problem is getting the Firestore APIs into your project.  Please post a new question that describes the new problem, showing the code you have that doesn't work the way you expect (especially the code where you include the relevant scripts).