# Firebase Reactjs - ae.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't figure out what is the error here. I made the tutorial Firebase/website and did the same things in my project. I am trying to print out the collection I created on Firebase in my React website but got the error at the line db.collection : `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ae.collection is not a function`

component.js :

```
// React
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db, collection, getDocs  } from '../../../firebase.js';

const [holder, setHolder] = useState([]); // update
  
  db.collection("holder").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    setHolder(
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        data: doc.data(),
      }))
    );
  });
  console.log({ holder });
```

update : firebase.js below

```
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
    import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
    
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
...
    };
    
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
    
    export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Thank you !

Comment: Can you share your `firebase.js` file ?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937892/db-firebase-database-is-not-a-function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Firebase Modular SDK which has a completely new syntax and you must use the same in your code. Try refactoring the code to this:

```
// React
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db } from '../../../firebase.js';
import { onSnapshot, collection } from 'firebase/firestore'

const [holder, setHolder] = useState([]); // update
 
onSnapshot(collection(db, 'holder'), (snapshot) => {
  setHolder(
    snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      data: doc.data(),
    }))
  );
})
```

Also make sure your `getFirestore` import is from `firebase/firestore` and not from `lite` in `firebase.js` or you'll run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69047904/how-to-solve-firebaseerror-expected-first-argument-to-collection-to-be-a-coll/69048162#69048162):

```
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
```

Comment: Hi ! can you recommand me a page where they explain how to access data with the new Modular sdk ?

Comment: All the document of one collection for exemple

Comment: @Hurinj yes you can check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) about fetching multiple documents.

Comment: thank you, any way to do it without a query and just taking all the documents in the collection ?